# HTML form not passing values to PHP script on localhost, wamp server

Tags: php, html

I have a WAMP server setup and I have the following form in file login.php

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" id="loginUsername" />
  Password: <input type="password" id="loginPassword" />
  <input type="submit" value="Log-in" id="login" />
</form>
```

And in the same file I have this PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    print "post is set";
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

However the print_r() never displays any of the field's values. I have tried using the get method in the form too.

Is this something to do with hosting on WAMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `name` attributes for your form elements. Without it those values will not be submitted.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" />
  Password: <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" />
  <input type="submit" value="Log-in" id="login" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must provide name attribute for the input element so that they can be available in the global variable $_GET ,$_POST or $_REQUEST. Remember id or class ,etc are for javascript/jquery/css processing and name attribute are server side processing (php ,jsp ,etc)

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name ="password"id="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log-in" id="login" />
</form>
```

hope it helps